Kong api-gateway does not route traffic to all services
I'm trying to expose three k8s services using Kong api gateway. I'm configuring the api gateway using the kong.yaml file (provided below). Every time I apply the ConfigMap which has (kong.yaml) and do a rollout restart of my kong deployment traffic either gets routed to hawcx-core-login-service or hawcx-core-reg-service and hawcx-anc-login-service but not all three. In other words, after every restart of my kong deployment, traffic either gets routed to hawcx-core-login-service or hawcx-core-reg-service and hawcx-anc-login-service but not all three.
What could I be possibly missing here, I feel I'm very close but I'm missing something. Please let me know what I can provide to better help me with this issue. I very much appreciate the help, thanks!
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kong-config
  namespace: kong
data:
  kong.yml: |
    _format_version: "1.1"
    services:
    - name: hawcx-core-login-service
      url: http://hawcx-core-login-service.hawcx-core-login.svc:80
      connect_timeout: 5000   
      read_timeout: 5000
      write_timeout: 5000
      routes:
      - paths:
        - /hc_login/docs
        - /hc_login/openapi.json
        - /hc_login/generateCipher
        - /hc_login/verifyCipher
        strip_path: false
        methods:
          - GET
          - POST
        hosts:
        - "a8b1d9a2dbe6d4f3a9855b5dc8a21151-2051416467.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
    
    - name: hawcx-anc-login-service
      url: http://hawcx-anc-login-service.hawcx-anc-login.svc:80
      connect_timeout: 5000   
      read_timeout: 5000
      write_timeout: 5000
      routes:
      - paths:
        - /ha_login/docs
        - /ha_login/openapi.json  
        - /ha_login/refresh_token
        - /ha_login/update/status
        - /ha_login/device/details
        - /ha_login/user
        strip_path: false 
        methods:
          - GET
          - POST
        hosts:
        - "a8b1d9a2dbe6d4f3a9855b5dc8a21151-2051416467.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
    
    - name: hawcx-core-reg-service
      url: http://hawcx-core-reg-service.hawcx-core-reg.svc:80
      connect_timeout: 5000   
      read_timeout: 5000
      write_timeout: 5000
      routes:
      - paths:
        - /hc_reg/docs
        - /hc_reg/openapi.json  
        - /hc_reg/add-user
        - /hc_reg/verify-user
        - /hc_reg/userexists
        - /hc_reg/createuser
        - /test-database # this is added to debug, should be removed
        strip_path: false 
        methods:
          - GET
          - POST
        hosts:
        - "a8b1d9a2dbe6d4f3a9855b5dc8a21151-2051416467.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com"


Your configuration looks sound, I tested it locally and because each service effectively has different prefixed routes it should just work. Only thing I can think of is your LB is doing something weird. How are you configuring your LB?
